# vba code that is in several cells and checks several ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Can anyone help
I have this formula in several cells, checking several ranges!
Is there a way for me to convert this to VBA so that i only have to select one range in each cell?

Thanks for the help.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Falhou")>0;"Falhou";IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Falhou Condicionamente")>0;"Falhou Condicionamente";IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Passou Condicionamente")>0;"Passou Condicionamente";IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Passou")>0;"Passou"))))
```

Comment: Can you explain what "i only have to select one range in each cell" would mean?

Comment: create a vba formula so the result is the same as the if. in the excel formula that i have i need to select several times the same range of cells! what i'm trying is a vba formula so that i only have to select the cell range one time! sorry if i couldn't explain very well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want, for it to work let's insert a module and put this code into this module.

Then just type following formulas:

`= Test (BE95: BE99)`

```
Function test(rng As Range)
Dim str As Variant
    For Each str In Array("Falhou", "Falhou Condicionamente", "Passou Condicionamente", "Passou")
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(str, rng, 0)) Then test = str:Exit for 'if match exist then return value
    Next str
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I just had to change the order of the results!

Comment: Isn't Exit For missing before Next str?

Comment: @VBasic2008 correct! I will fix it as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

The function below has one feature your worksheet function doesn't have: It returns "Falhou" if the range contains none of the 4 count criteria.

```
Function Passou(Rng As Range) As String

'    '=IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Falhou")>0;"Falhou";
'    IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Falhou Condicionamente")>0;"Falhou Condicionamente";
'    IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Passou Condicionamente")>0;"Passou Condicionamente";
'    IF(COUNTIF(BE95:BE99;"Passou")>0;"Passou"))))

    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Sp = Split("Falhou,Falhou Condicionamente,Passou Condicionamente,Passou", ",")
    For i = UBound(Sp) To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(Rng, Sp(i)) Then Exit For
    Next i
    Passou = Sp(i)
End Function
```

Call the UDF from the worksheet specifying the range to be searched.

```
= Passou($BE$95:$BE$99)
```

Absolute addressing of the range enables copying of the formula across rows and columns.